# Freemarker + Spring MVC tutorial

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm new to Spring MVC and Freemarker. So far I've used JSF and I have some experience with Ruby on Rails (concerning the RESTful pattern..).

I have my Spring web app configured and am now ready to try some basic stuff like forms and so on but I can't find any tutorials on using Spring MVC with freemarker. Since I have neither experience with Spring MVC nor Freemarker I'm quite lost where to start...

Should I try to understand freemarker first? I feel like Spring MVC, appart from the taglibs, just provides me with a way to setup a RESTful MVC app in a Spring context and that's it..?

Thank's for helpful links or even better some good books!

Comment: I maintain an operational example on my blog: http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/10/spring-freemarker-integration-example.html. It helps in addition to documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously official documentation can help you (**Spring MVC**): http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

In particular, you can refer to this chapter for configuring **Spring MVC + FreeMarker**: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-view-freemarker

For a general introduction to **Spring MVC** take a look also to this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/

Also this quick tutorial looks interesting (**Spring MVC 3 + FreeMarker**):
http://blog.teamextension.com/quick-freemarker-in-spring-3-tutorial-577

Comment: Yeah, official documentation.. don't know why I always forget about that one ;) Seems I need a spring.ftl file.. Is that standardized? Where can I get it? Or is it automatically imported with the freemarker dependency?

Comment: @Pete From the link I suggested you: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-bind-macros : _spring.ftl and are in the packages org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity or org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker respectively_